# How accurate is the portrayal of vikings in the TV series Vikings

Tags: historical-accuracy, vikings

I'm not too worried about the historical accuracy of the events in the tv series, but my question is specific to the portrayal of the viking's way of life, their appearance etc.

I know that we don't have time machines to go back and verify, but to what extent did the producers try to keep it in line with modern research? And are there aspects that one could say was not in line with archaeological findings?

Comment: related: http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/44041/what-is-the-connection-between-ragnar-from-vikings-and-ragnar-from-the-last-king?rq=1

Comment: Or you could do a bit of research on your own.

Comment: There is a companion documentary series, *Real Vikings*, which provides some insight into this topic.

Answer (score 1):

First thing I can say is that Ragnar and Rollo are not brothers in the real history, in fact they don't even know each other. Ragnar had 3 wives, Lagertha, Aslaug and Thóra, which you can't see in the series. But I know this much, if you really want to know some history behind vikings characters, watch this video, it helped me :)